# Unexpected behaviour using cell magic "%%time" in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I was just trying to import a dataframe to the notebook, running the following cell:

```
%%time
#df=pd.DataFrame()
#for chunk in pd.read_sql(qry,conn,chunksize=10**5):
#    df=pd.concat([df,chunk])
df=pd.read_csv(scriptdir+'\LocalSample\sample200k.txt', sep=";")
```

While it didn't return any error, when running the next command

```
df.head(20)
```

I received a name error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e9cb96795106> in <module>
----> 1 df.head(20)

NameError: name 'df' is not defined
```

Removing the `%%time` magic solved the issue.
Is this a known behaviour? Does anyone have any explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: Funny! Is this repeatable? Can you try to set a variable in another cell and repeat your test. Does the other variable survive, or is it deleted? If it's deleted, i guess, the content above killed the kernel (but then of course also the code above wouldn't be executable anymore until you reimport pandas).

Comment: @jottbe Hi, yes you can reproduce this yourself. Simply try:
`%%time
x=1+3`
and then in another cell try to call `x`